# 1с 7.7 + API Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, 1с, карты, яндекс-карты

Разбираюсь с яндекс картами. Больше всего интересует получение маршрута, разбитого на сегменты (не вывод на карту, а именно получение точек в текстовом файле или ещё как).

В песочнице написал такой запрос:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
    coords = [geolocation.latitude, geolocation.longitude],
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: coords,
            zoom: 13
        });
    ymaps.route([
        'Киров, улица Короленко 13',
        'Киров, улица Производственная 7'    
    ]).then(function (route) {
        myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
    });

}
```

Как его вызвать из 1с 7.7 и получить в ответ список точек?

Answer (score 0):

[Условия бесплатного использования](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) категорически запрещают использование некоммерческих тарифов в 1С. А среди коммерческих инструментов Яндекса для вашей задачи идеальным вариантом будет [API Построения маршрута](https://yandex.ru/dev/routing/router/) с запросами вида [https://api.routing.yandex.net/v2/route?waypoints=55.734494627139355,37.68191922355621|55.733441295701056,37.59027350593535&apikey=1b37b3ee-e975-4242-9e49-5323a63841b1](https://api.routing.yandex.net/v2/route?waypoints=55.734494627139355,37.68191922355621%7C55.733441295701056,37.59027350593535&apikey=1b37b3ee-e975-4242-9e49-5323a63841b1).